# relative path not working for images in css

Tags: php, css, apache, path, relative-path

I have the following file structure:

`C:/wamp/myproject/admin/webroot/images`

I have an index.php file lying inside the admin folder which calls a header.inc.php file lying in the same folder. header.inc.php has the following code-

```
<td align="left" valign="top" class="header-bg">
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
```

index.php calls a css file (css.css) through the following code:

```
<link href="<?php echo (WS_DIR_CSS); ?>/css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

The css lies in the following location:
`C:/wamp/myproject/admin/webroot/css`

The css files has a class which has the following code:

```
.header-bg {
  background:url(../images/header_bg.jpg) left top repeat-x;
  height:77px;
}
```

The image **header_bg.jpg** is not being displayed in the browser. Help anyone?

Comment: Is "images" its own directory in webroot (outside of the css directory)?

Answer (score 7):

the image is included relative to the css

if your image lives here...

```
/images
```

and your css lives here...

```
/somefolder/css/style.css
```

then the rule would be

```
background-image:url( ../../images/header_bg.jpg );
```

Can you check the element using firebug? Are there any rewrite rules that may be rerouting the request? Do you have read permissions on the image?

Comment: the rule must be `/images/header_bg.jpg`. Learn to use absolute addressing

Comment: Learn to read the OP, yes he *could* use absolute paths but that's not what he was doing in his example. Using ../../images/header_bg.jpg is perfectly valid and *will* work as described above.

Comment: i was answering unanswered questions. The solution posted works for the OP's problem, he didnt say anything about it working for other folders

Comment: Thanks @michael. Your answer solved my problem, upvote from me. Could you please let me know '../..' . I know the first 2 dots refer the folder above 'somefolder' but not sure about the remaining dots.

Answer (score 2):

*The image header_bg.jpg is not being displayed in the browser.*

There are a hundred possible reasons: from your browser set to block images, filesystem permissions denying read-access on the server.  Without knowing several more important details, a good start is figuring out if you're browser even tries to get the image.  This is where Firebug (via Firefox add-ons), or some other like browser plugin comes in handy.

Comment: +1 on using Firebug or some other debug tool to see where the problem really is.  With the code you've posted, there doesn't seem to be anything wrong, so it should work, which means there's something else going wrong other than your path.

Answer (score 0):

Look in your server logs to see which files is actually being requested. It's quite likely that you've got your URLs mixed up somewhere along the way.

Answer (score -4):

Relative addressing is not working by design.
That's why one should use absolute address.

1. Make yourself know what is actual header_bg.jpg address relative to site root.
   `/images/header_bg.jpg` for example.
2. Use that address.
   With or without WS_DIR_CSS helper, but in the HTML code it must be `/images/header_bg.jpg` or whatever absolute address is.

Comment: Relative addressing is not working by design. - This is completely false. Relative paths work perfectly fine.