# Image relative path in css

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, css, background-image

I,am developing an Asp.net website and have struck in an surprise thing. My Folder structure is as shown below:

```
- Styles
        - master.css
        - Images 
-webPages
-scripts
```

Now when i try to access an image in images folder from css, i get "**Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)** " error in chrome. The error only comes from the css file. I have used some images in my asp.net pages.It is working fine there.My example code for accessing an image in css is below

```
a.close { background-image: url(/images/close-arrow.png); background-position: left center; padding: 0 0 0 25px; }
```

I cannot understand what the problem is. Please Help me to sort this problem. Thanks in Advance

Comment: Try removing the forward slash before images.

Answer (score 1):

You have to mention path as `background-image: url(./images/close-arrow.png);`

because this is relative path.

Comment: Try background-image: url(../images/close-arrow.png);

Comment: refer below links, it might solve your problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2874018/relative-path-not-working-for-images-in-css and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2405333/css-background-image-path-issues.

Answer (score 0):

/images/close-arrow.png is not really a relative path. The leading / tells the script to start from your webroot. Just remove it and it is loaded relatively from the Styles folder

Comment: Is your folder really named Images with capital i? Then you should name it like that in your path too

Answer (score 0):

Put this code snippet in your `web.config`:

```
<location path="Images">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="*" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```